# this. doesn't show the correct name

Tags: javascript, closures, this, scopes

Why the console.log shows the name "Alex"? Why doesn't concatenate with the "David" name?

```
var Obj = function() {
    this.name = "Alex";
    var that = {};
    that.name = "David";
    var name = this.name + " && " + that.name;
    return name;
}

var o = new Obj();
console.log(o.name);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you invoke `Obj` as a constructor by using the `new` operator, always an object is returned. If the defined return value isn't of type `Object`, it's just ignored. Within `Obj` the object to be generated is referenced by `this`, that is, every property assigned to `this` is going to be a property of each generated object.

When you invoke `Obj` as a normal function, it just returns the defined return value and `this` is ignored.

`name` and `that` are just local variables with `Obj` as scope. They're not assigned to `this` and thus not part of the returned object. Since the return value `name` is of type `String`, it's simply ignored (if invoked as a constructor) and instead an object is returned, which contains all properties assigned to `this` (so `.name = "Alex"`):

```
var Obj = function () {
  var name = "David" // local variable
  this.name = "Alex" // name property of each newly generated object
  return name;
}

var o = new Obj(); // invoke function as a constructor
var p = Obj(); // normal function invocation

console.log(o); // {name: "Alex"}
console.log(p); // "David"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use it like below:

```
var Obj = function() {
    this.name = "Alex";
    var that = {};
    that.name = "David";
    this.objName = this.name + " && " + that.name;
    //return name;
}

var o = new Obj();
console(o.objName);
```

Or this, if you want to override `name`

```
var Obj = function() {
    this.name = "Alex";
    var that = {};
    that.name = "David";
    this.name = this.name + " && " + that.name;
    //return name;
}

var o = new Obj();
console(o.name);
```

Comment: _"name conflicts with local variable"_ Where do you see a conflict?

Comment: There's no conflict .. but when you call o.name .. it will return this.name of the object and not the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

When you call o.name it will return this.name of the object and not the declared variable ("name"). You need to update this.name value again

try this one :

```
var Obj = function() {
    this.name = "Alex";
    var that = {};
    that.name = "David";
    this.name = this.name + " && " + that.name;
}

var o = new Obj();
console.log(o.name);
```

Comment: Not quite right. The "return name;" is complete useless.

Comment: You're right .. i forgot to remove it .. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with the new Keyword.

One Solution is to get rid of the var keyword and then replace every name with this.name.

Or more simply get rid of the new keyword.  Because it will force your Object to return this.

If you are using the new key word this is what happens:

```js
var Foo = fuction(){
   var obj = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
   
    //your Foo code
   
   return obj;
    
}
```

Comment: _"Or more simply get rid of the new keyword"_ That doesn't work. It would require to change the rest of the code as well.

Answer (score 0):

`var Obj = function() {
    this.name = "Alex";
    var that = {};
    that.name = "David";
    this.name = this.name + " && " + that.name;
    return name;
}
var o = new Obj();
console.log(o.name);`